# Meteor: can google spider words from my database?

Tags: meteor, seo, web-crawler, keyword

lets say I'm making an online listing of clothing brands in Meteor. My question is, if all the name brands and texts are stored in the database, can google find those words and list my website accordingly? How does it work?

Comment: https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-seo-google-fetch-and-render.html This article might help you do understand more about seo in meteor.

Comment: okay, so googlebot might render your page? That means it would render it with the data? Can you elaborate a bit please?

Answer (score 0):

This meteor package is probably what you're looking for: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable

Comment: does the spider go through just the HTML? So if all my clothing brand names are written in MongoDB, not in the HTML, will the spider read it at all?